# Flag the first 3 and last 2 working days in a calendar table

Tags: sql, date, pyspark

I have an auxiliary table in my database that contains all the days of the year with a column (is_working_day) that is a boolean flag indicating whether that day is a business day or not.

I would like to build a query on this table that allows me to mark the last 2 business days of a month and the first three sequentially (1, 2, 3, 4, 5). Is it possible?

The output should be something like:

| day | is_working_day | flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2023 | 0 | 0 |
| 02/01/2023 | 1 | 1 |
| 03/01/2023 | 1 | 2 |
| 04/01/2023 | 1 | 0 |
| 05/01/2023 | 1 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 29/01/2023 | 1 | 3 |
| 30/01/2023 | 1 | 4 |
| 31/01/2023 | 1 | 5 |
| 01/02/2023 | 1 | 1 |
| 02/02/2023 | 1 | 2 |

Day and is_working day already exists in my table, what i would like is some logic to create the "flag" column.

Comment: You want to add the flag column using sql query?

Comment: Yes @SalmanA - via SQL Query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If SQL-only solution is acceptable then you can use window functions to generate the flag column. One example:

```
with cte as (
    select *
         , sum(is_working_day) over (partition by datepart(year, day), datepart(month, day) order by day) as rn
         , sum(is_working_day) over (partition by datepart(year, day), datepart(month, day)) as mv
    from t
)
select day
     , is_working_day
     , case
           when is_working_day = 1 and rn >= 1 and rn <= 2 then rn
           when is_working_day = 1 and rn > mv - 3 then 5 - (mv - rn)
       end as flag
from cte
```

Result:

| day | is_working_day | flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 0 | *null* |
| 2023-01-02 | 1 | 1 |
| 2023-01-03 | 0 | *null* |
| 2023-01-04 | 1 | 2 |
| 2023-01-05 | 1 | 3 |
| 2023-01-29 | 1 | 4 |
| 2023-01-30 | 0 | *null* |
| 2023-01-31 | 1 | 5 |
| 2023-02-01 | 1 | 1 |
| 2023-02-02 | 1 | 2 |

Replace date part extraction functions with those available in your RDBMS.

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RyriN58H)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import Window
ab=ab.withColumn("Day",to_date(col("Day"),"dd-mm-yyyy"))
ab=ab.withColumn("Month",month(col("Day")))
w0=Window.partitionBy('month','is_working_day').orderBy('Day')
w1=Window.partitionBy('month','is_working_day')
ab=ab.withColumn("row",row_number().over(w0))



ab=ab.withColumn("flag",when((col("is_working_day")==1) & (col("row")==1),1)\
                       .when((col("is_working_day")==1) & (col("row")==2),2)\
                       .when((col("is_working_day")==1) & (col("row")==max(col("row")).over(w1)),5)\
                       .when((col("is_working_day")==1) & (col("row")==max(col("row")).over(w1)-1),4)\
                       .when((col("is_working_day")==1) & (col("row")==max(col("row")).over(w1)-2),3)\
                       .otherwise(0))
```

Comment: Thanks, but did not work, although we use pyspark, i'm limited to "Metabase" and cant import any library :(